# Sequence space endowed with product topology

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $Y=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{(N)}}$ be the space of finite sequences and $X$ be its infinite counter part. I want to find a neighborhood basis for $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in Y$ and $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in X$.

For the finite case I define $e_n=\left (\delta_{i,n}\right )_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ as a basis vector and the created linear subspace as basis for $Y$. Now for the neighborhood basis I define $e_{n,y}=e_n\cdot  y_n$ and take $\left (e_{n,y}\right )_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ to be the neighborhood basis of $(y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

I am not sure what to do with the infinite space. Also I am not even sure why the space $Y$ is called a finite one, since we have countably infinite basis vectors. Infinity is a strange thing.

Comment: Do You mean $Y=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}:\exists n:\forall m>n:x_m=0\}$ and $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\backslash Y$ and do You want to take $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as a Hamel basis for $Y$? What topology are You considering on the space $Y$? With this definition $X$ is no vector space ( with pointwise operation)...

Comment: Yes, exactly. The topology was chosen to be the product topology. Why should $X$ not be a vs? I think $X$ is a subspace of $Y$ and therefore a vector space again.

Comment: $X$ definitely is a vector space, simply an infinite direct product. Also who calls $Y$ finite? I've never heard that. Even $\mathbb{R}$ is not finite, the nomenclature doesn't make sense. Also you say you are looking for neighbourhood basis, yet you chose sequences. In topological sense the neighbourhood basis is a subset of topology, so it's a collection of sets, each being a collection of sequences in your case. I think we need a clarification on what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: I noticed I missed brackets. Of course this question did not make any sense.

Comment: @freakish I think we need some clarification indeed. If by "$X$ its infinite counterpart" is ment $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}\backslash Y$ it is definitely $\textbf{no}$ subspace as can be seen from $\underbrace{(0,1,1,...)}_{\in X}+\underbrace{(0,-1,-1,...)}_{\in X}=(0,0,....)\notin X$

Comment: @EpsilonDelta A difference with respect to "infinity" from $\mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is that the first space has a dense countable subset ( and thus a countable Schauder basis), i.e. it is separable, and the second space is not separable

Comment: $X$ is defined to be $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, this is what I meant with "infinite counterpart". I simply can not think of a neighborhood basis, I even doubt it really exists.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood "infinite counterpart". Since $X$ is not separable You cant´t find a countable neighborhood basis.

Comment: Could I simply use epsilon balls around each coordinate of a vector of $X$ and $Y$? I could then create a neighborhood basis. But I fear this might be too simple.

Comment: Of course the $\varepsilon$-balls are a classical neighborhood basis in every metric space, but for a nonseparable space it is probably the best thing You can do without too much effort

Comment: $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is certainly separable in the product topology, and metrisable too. @PeterMelech

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Ok, thanks. I suspected it is not separable, because $\ell^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})\subset \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ isn´t separable, but this is endowed with the topology induced by the supremum norm, what is a dense countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ wrt the product topology?

Comment: @PeterMelech all sequences that are rational and eventually $0$ is countable and dense.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I see that these are dense in $Y=\mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})}$ ( in the OPs notation), but not why these are dense in $X=\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: @PeterMelech every basic open set in the product topology only “lives” only on finitely many coordinates.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Of course! That is so by definition of the product topology! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neighhbourhood base for a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, whether it's infinite or has a finite support (if I understand the OP's question correctly; a "finite sequence" has only finitely many non-zero terms; or we fill up a finite sequence by adding $0$'s) is all sets of the form, where $F \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is finite and $\varepsilon >0$ is a real number:

$$U((x_n), F, \varepsilon) = \{ (y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} (\,\text{resp. } \mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})}): \forall n \in F: |x_n - y_n| < \varepsilon\}$$

This can be made a countable local base if we replace $\varepsilon >0$ by $\frac{1}{m}$ and let $m = 1,2,3,\ldots$, instead; there are only countably many finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. This topology is separable metrisable (for both spaces).